# autofac mvc pass by ref error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am using MVC 5 with autofac and in my my controller I call an action method that calls a method with ref parameter. When i try to browse to browse to the action method I get the below error that suggest that I can not use ref parameters. Is that correct?

> Cannot call action method
>   'AllThings.WebUI.Models.SearchCriteriaViewModel
>   SetListData(System.String,
>   AllThings.WebUI.Models.SearchCriteriaViewModel ByRef,
>   AllThings.Entities.Abstracts.ISimpleService, Double)' on controller
>   'AllThings.WebUI.Controllers.PostController' because the parameter
>   'AllThings.WebUI.Models.SearchCriteriaViewModel&
>   searchCriteriaViewModel' is passed by reference. Parameter name:
>   methodInfo

cut down the code and the main code looks like this:

```
[Route("~/{site}/{CategoryUrl?}")]
    [Route("~/{country:maxlength(2)}/{site}/{CategoryUrl?}", Name="ResultList")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult List(string country, string site, SearchCriteriaViewModel searchCriteriaViewModel)
    {
        SetListData(site, ref searchCriteriaViewModel, simpleService, CommonLibrary.Helpers.GetCountryTimeZoneOffSet(countryIso2));

        return View("List", searchCriteriaViewModel);
    }

 public SearchCriteriaViewModel SetListData(string site, ref SearchCriteriaViewModel searchCriteriaViewModel, ISimpleService simpleService, double utcOffset)
    {
        SearchCriteria searchCriteria = EntityFactory.GetSearchCriteria();

        if (searchCriteriaViewModel.Category == null)
        {
            searchCriteriaViewModel.Category = new Category();
        }


        return searchCriteriaViewModel;
    }
```

my autofac config looks like this

```
public static void Initialize()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutoFacDependencyResolver(RegisterServices(builder)));
    }

    private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        //builder.RegisterType<AllThings.Entities.Concrete.ContextFactory>().As<IContextFactory>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<AllThings.Entities.Concrete.SimpleService>().As<ISimpleService>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<AllThings.Entities.Concrete.EFSimpleRepository>().As<ISimpleRepository>().InstancePerRequest();


        //builder.RegisterInstance(GetMockContext()).As<IContextFactory>(); 
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Comment: Show your code. Why do you want to pass this parameter by reference?

Comment: I have the action method call another method and pass the parameter by ref so I can update it in the methodand so the action method get the updated object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect the `ref` parameter to do? Your action method gets called using reflection, based on an incoming HTTP request. It's not like if you modify the `ref` parameter, the object on the client changes too - it's entirely disconnected through the nature of HTTP.

Just remove the `ref` modifier.

Comment: it is not my action method that has the ref in its signature the ref is in the signature of another private method that the action method calls

Comment: MVC sees it as an action method candidate. Make it private.

Comment: Are are a star, that fixed the issue. Thanks heaps!